# Opera unexpectedly quits with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, opera

My Opera browser quit, after few seconds after being launch by web driver Opera-chromium. I have the  Web-driver Opera-Chromium installed (version  0.2.2 on WIN 64 Bits, Running Selenium version 3.0.1).

Code:

```csharp
DesiredCapabilities capabilit = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:/browser-drivers/operadriver.exe"); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:/Program Files/Opera x64/opera.exe");

capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
OperaDriver browser = new OperaDriver(capability);

WebDriver driver = browser;
```

As a result Opera is launched correctly:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Gast\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-681906726\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting OperaDriver 0.2.0 (ba47709ed9e35ce26dbd960fb5d75be104290d96) on port 11091
Only local connections are allowed.
Nov 18, 2016 11:04:04 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
```

but after few seconds  the following lines appear within Selenium:

```
Nov 18, 2016 11:08:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

at that point Opera quit.

I tried several Opera version, but not able to keep Opera open after Selenium `createSession`, the web driver itself remains open.

Comment: An answer was provided by @user7619182, but it was deleted by the community. Here's the text: *"Solved the issue, can launch the WEB Browser: the latest version that can be used with Selenium is Build: 29.0.1795.41 Opera Next One"*.